# rgb transparent colors in plotly and R

Tags: r, rgb, plotly

I am trying to get a plotly graph with a filled area that is semi-transparent purple. I can find the rgb designation fine and get it to work in a simple plot. But it seems that plotly doesn't read in rgb's the usual way?

```
plot(rnorm(10),col="#A020F066",pch=15,cex=13)
# plots squares that are transparent purple (expected)
```

[image: plot with purple squares]

```
p=plot_ly(x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(1,2,5,10),type="scatter",line=list(color="red"))
p=add_trace(p,x=c(1,2,3,4),y=c(11,12,15,20),type="scatter",
        fillcolor="#A020F066",fill="tonexty",
        line=list(width=10),marker=list(size=10))
p
# plots area that is transparent mint green (What? I expected purple)
```

[image: plot with green fill]

Answer (score 14):

According to the plotly website, the full list of rgb / hex available is found here (http://reeddesign.co.uk/test/namedcolors.html). So for your example, you would need to use `fillcolor="#8a2be2"`. Alternatively, you can also use something like this `fillcolor="rgba(147,112,219,0.1)` with the last digit being the alpha (opacity)

Comment: Figured it out myself. R reads "#A020F066" as color A020F0 and transparency (in hex) 66. So last 2 digits control opacity. Plotly reads the A0 as the transparency part and the last 6 digits as the color. Opacity last in general R, Opacity first in plotly. Using this trick I can get my plot to reproduce the mint green or the plotly to be the transparent purple I want.

Comment: I've tried adding the two digits and it isn't working. Anyone could solve this?