# How to fill in the area below trendline in plotly express scatterplot?

Tags: python, plotly-express

I've drawn a scatterplot with a non-linear trendline and a vertical line:

```
import plotly.express as px
uk_age = df[df['CountryLive']=='United Kingdom']['Age'].mean()

fig = px.scatter(df, x=x, y=y, trendline="lowess", trendline_options=dict(frac=0.4), 
                 trendline_color_override="red",template='plotly_white', range_y=[0,30])
fig.add_vline(x=uk_age, annotation_text="UK", 
              annotation_position="top right", line_color="blue")
fig.show()
```

1. I would like to fill the area below the trendline.
2. I would like to fill the area below the trendline, but only to the right of the
   vline (like on the drawing below, apologies for my art skills)

[image: desired output]

I've played around with extracting the trendline results and plotting them again, but couldn't fill them. The fact that it's a smoothened trendline(frac=0.4), not a 'normal' plot line makes it a difficult task. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can get the desired output by getting the trend line drawing data and drawing an area graph with it. I don't know the cause, but setting the transparency didn't work, so I shaded it with color.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, 
                 x="total_bill",
                 y="tip", 
                 trendline="lowess",
                 trendline_options=dict(frac=0.1),
                 trendline_color_override='red',
                 template='plotly_white'
                )

x_pos = 9.94
x = fig.data[1]['x']
y = fig.data[1]['y']
x = [pos for pos in x if pos >= x_pos]
y = y[len(y) - len(x):]
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, 
                         line_color='rgba(147,112,219,0.3)',
                         fillcolor='pink',
                         opacity=0.1,
                         fill='tozeroy'))

fig.add_vline(x=x_pos, annotation_text='UK',annotation_position='top right', line_color='Blue')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: that's almost the winner, now just the vertical line border, I've managed to sort out the opacity: fillcolor="rgba(147,112,219,0.3)"   from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35213766/rgb-transparent-colors-in-plotly-and-r

Comment: I overlooked another requirement. Extract the value of the trend line data or more based on the position of the vertical line x-axis and make it the x-axis. Then replace it with the same position as the y-axis data. There may be a better way to do this. I replaced the code and the graph.

Comment: thanks, that solves it...and creates another problem: why the border of filling can only be marked in integers? the horizontal line on my chart is float (28.62), but lets say it's 9.5 on yours. The filling starts either on 9 or 10  on x axis, dont understand why.

Comment: It does not have to be an integer. I took the liberty of drawing a vertical line from the x-axis to 10, so I extracted the values after 10.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/0X9wJug think it only starts filling from the point where trendline breaks, I've also tried manually setting the point and couldnt move it like a float, could only move by 1

Comment: take that back, it only fills from integer numbers on x axis, trendline breakpoints don't matter, but still... can't start filling at 9.5... or 28.62...

Comment: The equal condition was missing in the judgment for extracting the fill range, so the code has been fixed.

Comment: that's the first thing I've tried, no luck there.

Comment: Now get the value of the x-axis and set x,y with the value of the x-axis you want to make a vertical line. `fig.data['x']`

Comment: genius! fig.data[1]['x'][13] = uk_age,  not very efficient set up that I have to manually dig in that array, but it works, ... thank you very much